# How to get initial indexed data for my own search engine?

Tags: javascript, php, search, web-crawler, search-engine

I am trying to make a search engine.I want to know that How can I get *URLs in start* to index in my Database? For example , How google got the URLs of websites for crawling?

Comment: Google hungrily vaccumed up every last URL they could find, whereever it came from. There was a stage where SEs were in a numbers war and inflated their databases with a massive URL count for the purpose of "winning" the marketing. Where did they get them? Everywhere. For example many people would type URLs in the google search box, added to spider queue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with an existing Index and use it to build your own index. dmoz is a human editable index: http://www.dmoz.org/

Comment: ok so How can I query to dmoz to get initial data? Do they some API or what?

Comment: If your search engine has a crawler, you could just start by pointing it at dmoz.org ;)

Comment: thanks :) Do you know some javascript based crawlers which can I add in for my search engine?